# nmap to scan all resolved ip addresses for a given domain name?

Tags: nmap, network-scanners, host-discovery

I'm using nmap to scan a given domain name example.com, which resolves to 2 ip addresses, then nmap chooses only one ip address to scan

for example:

```
#nmap -vv -sV scanme.nmap.org
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-01 15:52 CET
NSE: Loaded 35 scripts for scanning.
Warning: Hostname scanme.nmap.org resolves to 2 IPs. Using 45.33.32.156.
Initiating Ping Scan at 15:52
Scanning scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156) [4 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 15:52, 0.17s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:52
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:52, 0.30s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 15:52
Scanning scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Discovered open port 9929/tcp on 45.33.32.156
```

is there an option to force nmap to scan all 2 ip address, not just one? thanks

Comment: prefer to ask questions related to information security

Comment: usually you would first scan that entire network range, then submit the IP addresses into nmap as a list

Comment: dig +short <domainname>  | sudo xargs nmap -vv -sV

Comment: i'm aware of these workarounds, thanks, but I'm asking to see if nmap have an option to support this natively

Answer (score 9):

Nmap has a script to do this, [`resolveall`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/resolveall.html). The interface isn't as nice as it could be: you have to provide the hostname via the `resolveall.hosts` script argument. Here's how to do that and also add any resolved addresses to the scan queue:

```
nmap --script resolveall --script-args newtargets,resolveall.hosts=example.com
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, Nmap 7.40 and later does not require the `resolveall.hosts` script argument; you can provide targets directly on the command line or with `-iL` as you usually would. The `newtargets` argument *is* required to add the resolved addresses to the scan queue instead of just listing them in the script's output. Future releases of Nmap (newer than 7.60) will have non-NSE capability to do this, but the options and syntax have not been decided yet.

EDIT 2: Nmap 7.70 (released today) has this functionality built-in with the `--resolve-all` option. No need to use the `resolveall` NSE script, which will be removed in a future release, and no need to use the `newtargets` script argument.

Comment: Thanks! but what if I have a text file with a list of domain names, can I use the -iL option, or there's an alternative?

Comment: @ksr I just added this to the script last night. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: great! r u the author? can u give us link to the modified version? thanks!

Comment: can u provide an example command with arguments, how the new modified version will be used with nmap

Comment: @ksr download from the documentation page: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/resolveall.html . Example: `nmap -iL targets.txt --script resolves --script-args newtargets`

Comment: This does not seem to work with nmap 7.93, even with --resolve-all, it still lists the IPv6 of the target in the "other addresses" list, if also passing `-6`, it will list the IPv4 in other addresses. It still picks one address instead of all. This answer only seems to scan all IP addresses from the selected family, instead of all the addresses of the target

Answer (score 1):

There is a "--resolve-all" parameter since Nmap 7.70 [2018-03-20] which does just that
https://nmap.org/changelog.html

> To make Nmap scan all the resolved addresses instead of only the first
>   one, use the --resolve-all option.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a for loop:
`for srv in $(host example.com |awk '{print $4}'); do nmap $srv; done`

or if you have a list with one entry per line:
`for srv in $(cat list.txt); do nmap $srv; done`